Confusion on proof of "dimension of the fiber is an upper semicontinuous function on the source" (From Vakil FOAG, Theorem 12.4.3).
I'm confused on a step of the proof of Theorem 12.4.3(a) in Vakil's FOAG (from the February 21, 2024 version). The theorem states:

Suppose $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of finite type $k$-schemes. Then the dimension of the fiber of $\pi$ at $p \in X$ (defined to be the dimension of the largest component of $\pi^{-1}(\pi(p))$ containing $p$) is an upper semicontinuous function in $p$ (i.e., on $X$).

The proof begins with an exercise asking me to reduce to the case when $X$ and $Y$ are integral and $\pi$ is dominant, and I do see how this is done. They define $F_n \subset X$ to be the set of points with fiber dimension at least $n$, and proceed by trying to show by induction on the dimension of $Y$ that each set $F_n$ is closed, noting that the base case where $\dim Y = 0$ is trivial. The next line is what confuses me. It reads

Let $r = \dim X - \dim Y$ be the "relative dimension" of $\pi$. If $n \leq r$, then $F_n = X$ by Exercise 12.4.A and Theorem 12.2.9.

I don't see how to make the conclusion that $F_n = X$ when $n \leq r$. I believe this requires me to show that every irreducible component of every fiber of $\pi$ has dimension at least $r$.
Exercise 12.4.A states

Suppose $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of locally Noetherian schemes and $p \in X$ and $q \in Y$ are points such that $\pi(p) = q$. Then $$\text{codim}_X (p) \leq \text{codim}_Y (q) + \text{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)} (p)$$

and Theorem 12.2.9 reads

Suppose $X$ is a pure-dimensional $k$-scheme locally of finite type and $Y$ is an irreducible closed subset. Then $$\dim X = \dim Y + \text{codim} Y$$

I understand that $X$ and $Y$ in this proof, after the reductions, satisfy the hypotheses of both results. I also see that if $p \in X$ is a closed point, its codimension is $\dim Y + r$, so $$r = \dim Y + r - \dim Y \leq \text{codim}_X(p) - \text{codim}_Y(\pi(p)) \leq \text{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(\pi(p))}(p)$$
and thus the fiber dimension at $p$ is at least $r$. I don't, however, see how this argument extends to non-closed points. Is there a similar sequence of inequalities that works?

Let $q\in Y$ be arbitrary and let $p\in X$ be the generic point of an irreducible component of the fiber $X_q$. Then $\operatorname{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)}(p)=0$, so $\operatorname{codim}_X(p) \leq \operatorname{codim}_Y(q)$ by 12.4.A. Applying 12.2.9, we have $\dim X - \dim \overline{\{p\}} \leq \dim Y - \dim \overline{\{q\}}$, which rearranges to $r=\dim X - \dim Y \leq  \dim \overline{\{p\}} - \dim \overline{\{q\}}$.
Now I claim that $r \leq \dim \overline{\{p\}} - \dim \overline{\{q\}}$ implies that the closure of $p$ inside $\pi^{-1}(q)$ is of dimension at least $r$. Recall that taking closure in $X$, we have $\dim \overline{\{p\}} = \operatorname{trdeg} k(p)/k$ and taking closure in $Y$, we have $\dim \overline{\{q\}} = \operatorname{trdeg} k(q)/k$. Now consider taking the closure of $p$ inside $X_q = X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k(q)$, a scheme of finite type over the field $k(q)$: the dimension of the closure of $p$ in $X_q$ is equal to the transcendence degree of $k(p)$ over $k(q)$. But since transcendence degree adds in towers of field extensions, we have $$\operatorname{trdeg} k(p)/k(q) = \operatorname{trdeg} k(p)/k -\operatorname{trdeg} k(q) = \dim \overline{\{p\}} - \dim \overline{\{q\}} \geq r,$$ proving that the closure of $p$ inside $X_q$ is of dimension at least $r$, and we win.

Wait, take $X = \mathbb{A}^2_k$, $Y = \mathbb{A}^1_k$, and let $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ be the associated to the inclusion $k[x] \rightarrow k[x,y]$. The preimage of $(y)$ under the ring map is $(0)$, the generic point. But $(y)$ has codimension 1 in $\mathbb{A}^2$, while the generic point has codimension 0 in $\mathbb{A}^1_k$, which seems to contradict the claim $\operatorname{codim}_X (p) \leq \operatorname{codim}_Y (q)$. Have I made a mistake here?

@Ice2water no, that's correct, it was my mistake - I needed $p$ to be a generic point of an irreducible component of the fiber over $q$. I think I've fixed it now, apologies for the previous error(s).
